# Excel - match data from one range to another and return either another value from a third range OR the original data

Tags: excel, formula, vlookup

I'm trying to work with impure data to create a clean template.  Right now, I receive an excel document that has a lot of errors in it, but they're always the same errors.  Rather than manually going in and fixing it every time, I'd like to set up a formula to automatically fix the errors.

For example, I have a list of values in Sheet 1, column A that always contains the same errors.  I have a validation sheet (Sheet2) that contains all the error values in column A and the correct values in column B.  I'd like to set up a third tab (Sheet3) that contains a formula that compares the values from Sheet1 column A against the values in Sheet2, and if present displays the corrected  value from column B, otherwise it displays the original (correct) value from Sheet1 column A.

I think the formula would be similar to the one I [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780192/excel-match-data-from-one-range-to-another-and-get-the-value-from-the-cell-to) which returns the corrected values for the errors, I just need that last step that returns the original value instead of #NA if there isn't an error.  Something like this:

> =VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!A2,'Sheet2'!A:B,2,'Sheet1'!A2)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14780334/438971) on the question you mentioned shows you how to use `IFERROR()` to catch the `#N/A`.  Instead of the `""` blank string, you want the original value instead, which is your value from `Sheet1`.

Comment: Something like (in `Sheet3!A2`) : `=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$B,MATCH(Sheet1!$A2,Sheet2!$A:$A,0)), Sheet1!$A2)`

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of an answer and same principle as @Orbling. Assumes all columns are labelled:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0),Sheet1!A2)
```

in Sheet3 A2 and copied down to suit.