# Return multiple values from a range

Tags: excel

To return a value corresponding to another cell from a range if it matches with a cell, I found Chuff's solution helpful (in 
[Excel - match data from one range to another and get the value from the cell to the right of the matched data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780192/excel-match-data-from-one-range-to-another-and-get-the-value-from-the-cell-to) ):

=iferror(vlookup(b31,$f$3:$g$12,2,0),"")

However, if there are more than one cells within the column F which match with b1, the formula returns the value of only one cell from the column G.

Could it be modified so as to attract the value of more than one cell?

Thank you!

Comment: In the case of multiple matches, how do you want the values from the  corresponding cells of column G to be presented? eg in adjacent cells, or coerced into a single using an operation such as `SUM()` (if they are all numeric) or concatenation  (otherwise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return multiple corresponding Vlookup values you should use this formula: `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$9,SMALL(IF($E1=$A$2:$A$9,ROW($A$2:$A$9)-ROW($A$2)+1),COLUMN(A1))),"")`
Because it it an array formula, please enter it using combination of `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` . For example, if you have you lookup range in `A:B` column, and lookup values in `D` column, then please enter formula above to `F1` cell, then drag it to the right and to the bottom. You should now see all instances of Vlookup next to the lookup value in `D` column.

[image]

If you have only values which you want to sum in case they correspond to your value in cell `B31`, then simply use `SUMIF` formula like this `=SUMIF($F$3:$F$10,$B31,$G$3:$G$10)` entered in cell `C31`.

[image]

Comment: L, I'm greatful to you for your help.

Comment: How to? I tried but couldn't. Moreover, I can't vote. So sorry!

Comment: Click the checkmark under this post, on the left. (I think it's right below the arrows). As the author of the question, you'll see an outline of a checkmark on the left side of each answer. It'll be right below the up and down vote arrows. Click the checkmark next to the post.

Comment: Yes, it did. Thank you